# Why a component doesn't want to export when i use connect function in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, mern

I am beginner in Redux with React. I followed some courses where the instructors used Redux for managing state. For some components, when I used the connect function, the components export normally. But for others, I used the same syntax, the components didn't want to export. When I removed the connect function, it worked but when I put it back, it didn't work anymore. I copy and and paste the instructor's code, it gave me the same error.

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{})(Component);
```

This is where I have the error.

Comment: you misspelled `default`

Comment: What error are you seeing exactly?

Comment: @twils0 No error output, the component doesn't want export when i use export default connect()(Component)

Comment: Well, it should work. It sounds like it does work for you with some components. Do you notice any differences between the components that work and the components that do not work? We don't have a lot to go on here, to help figure out the issue.

Comment: It should work but I don't know why it's not the case. When I created the component, I imported all files or modules I needed without write any JSX. So when I put : `export default Component`, the component is exported so I can used it anywhere. But when I put :  `export default connect()(Component)` the component did't export so I cannot imported it in other components.

Comment: @twils0 I copy and paste the instructor's code, it still gives me the same kind of problem.

Comment: @Charles-HébertDalzon Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj7px08qy9?file=/Page.js)?

Comment: @HMR This is an exemple : `import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PostItem = ({ post }) => {
  return <div></div>;
};

PostItem.propTypes = {
  post: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default connect()(PostItem);
`

Comment: @Charles-HébertDalzon How do you know it's not exporting? Please let us know exactly what's happening. How are you importing this component, and what error do you get exactly when trying to import?

Comment: @twils0 I use VS code, it gives me description of a component when I hover it. The path is correct for importing the component is correct. When I use the connect() method in the sentence export  default  connect()(Component), it gives an error : "Component not found" when I remove the connect (), it works.